# problem to convert timestamp format to char

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle-apex

having this query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
   (    
    "CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EFFECTIVEDATE" TIMESTAMP (6)
)
```

if I make a simple query to EFFECTIVEDATE column, look like this (after some insert)
query:

```
select EFFECTIVEDATE
from my_table;
```

[image]

But if i want format that timestamp ...
query:

```
select to_char(mt.EFFECTIVEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') as "EffectiveDate"
from my_table mt
```

[image]

**why it add those values into HH:MM:SS ?**

**What should i do to fix this? i need those values as a STRING**

It must look like this:

```
2020-06-26 00:00:00
2020-06-24 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

I'm using oracle 19.

Comment: get the date and append `00:00:00`

Comment: could be good.
I also thought about it, but I think there must be another way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using `MM` instead of `MI`.

- `MM` - Month
- `MI` - Minute

You should use: `to_char(mt.EFFECTIVEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')`

`HH` represents in 12 hour and `HH24` represents 24 hour format

Comment: modifying : select to_char(mt.EFFECTIVEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as "EffectiveDate" from HS_CPQ_COSTCHANNELDISCOUNT mt - The result is something like this 
2020-06-26 12:00:00 | 
2020-06-24 12:00:00, now i don't the minutes but i see "12"

Comment: i got it --- the rigth query will be:  select to_char(mt.EFFECTIVEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as "EffectiveDate" from HS_CPQ_COSTCHANNELDISCOUNT mt;